# How can I not show divs(sidebars) when site is in mobile viewport

Tags: css, viewport

I want to have 2 sidebars on my site. I have a responsive CSS using viewport. But I don't want to show sidebars when the site is opened in mobile browsers. Tab would do fine. Is there some way I can do so?

For example: Stack Overflow. When you open it in mobile, you don't see the sidebars. I want something similar like this.

Comment: Why -1? O.o I have used viewport. But everything becomes a mess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **media query** for this mobile only define :

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Read this for more http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: That's what I was looking for. I tried media query before but I wrote the whole css again in { STYLES } -_- Thanks :)

Comment: @sandeep Please do you think you could help me with this question http://goo.gl/Yl5qIi

Answer (score 1):

You can use media-queries and selectively show/hide the sidebar (change the sidebar class as applicable in the below code) like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .sidebar {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: OP wants for mobile browsers. So,define  **max-device-width**

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But just curious, won't `max-width` work as well?

Comment: max-width effect the desktop version also :)

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow has a custom HTML for mobile pages.

But you could try [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)